# Перехват ошибки 'WebSocket connection'

Tags: javascript, websocket

Можно ли как-то перехватить ошибку:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Или нет? Пробовал через `try catch` не помогло.

**UPD:**

Копнув немного глубже - Ошибка происходит внутри библиотеки `injected` в методе:

```
function WrappedWebSocket(url, ...args) {
    // Throw correct exceptions if the constructor is used improperly.
    if (!(this instanceof WrappedWebSocket)) return RealWebSocket();
    if (arguments.length < 1) return new RealWebSocket();

    let websocket = new RealWebSocket(url, ...args);

    checkRequest("websocket", websocket.url, blocked =>
    {
      if (blocked)
        closeWebSocket(websocket);
    });

    return websocket;
}
```

На строчке:

```
let websocket = new RealWebSocket(url, ...args);
```

Comment: так это разве js ошибка?

Comment: @Hipster, ну естественно, а чего же это по вашему ошибка?

Comment: `var ws = new WebSocket('url'); ws.onerror = function(evt) { ... };`

Comment: @ArchDemon, - это то тут причем, - это ничего не изменит, будет и та и та, которую определить в `onerror`. Вообщем эта ошибка исходит изнутри, никак ее походу нельзя перехватить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данную ошибку перехватить нельзя.